# maven command for viewing classpath

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I know this command - `mvn dependency:build-classpath` . But I want to see compile time classpath , test classpath and runtime classpath . What are commands for each of them ?

Comment: You can see them via debugging option like `mvn -X compile` and redirect the output to a file and search for `test-classpath` for example...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use variations of this command, try

```
mvn dependency:build-classpath -DincludeScope=compile
```

or

```
mvn dependency:build-classpath -DincludeScope=runtime
```

or

```
mvn dependency:build-classpath -DincludeScope=test
```

(which is the default)

Comment: This only shows jars. I wanted to see my target folders too where `.class` files are present in case of say runtime.

Comment: in this case, the answer from @khmarbaise is the one you can use. You also can set the maven-compiler-plugin to show you more about it's internals while compiling with -Dmaven.compiler.verbose=true. Why do you also want to see the outputfolder, too? Why do you want to see this?

Comment: It's not about why. It's about complete details in my classpath variable. After all , even that folder must be added in classpath ?

Comment: yes, this folder is added. maven-compiler-plugin uses the compile-classpath, so the debug messages of this plugin will show it to you. another plugin - f.e. the exec-maven-plugin uses by default the runtime-classpath, so the debug messages of this plugin will show it to you

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to SEE the different classpaths, then the maven-antrun-plugin may help you here. the [examples page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/examples/classpaths.html) shows exactly what you need.